# Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Constantly Refreshing

Tags: java, spring

My webapp creates PDFs dynamically using iText. GlassFish thread pool is used to process each PDF in a separate thread. Spring is sprinkled throughout the application for dependency injection. All modules of the app are accessed through web services from a separate UI application.

**Problem:**
Spring is constantly refreshing during runtime. It seems to happen mainly after one of the web services is called. The service is relatively simple, and it uses service/DAO interfaces injected by Spring (via XML configuration). There is no Java code that directly uses Spring or calls a refresh().

I see this in the log file after almost every call to the above service:

```
INFO ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:411 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@26fa7f9: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@26fa7f9]; startup date [Fri Feb 28 07:50:01 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:323 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [locale.xml]
INFO ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:426 - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@26fa7f9]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b5c2f0c
INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:414 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b5c2f0c: defining beans [messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Please help me understand why Spring is refreshing all the time. I thought Spring was only supposed to initialize during startup.

Comment: Are you creating the .pdf files on the server file system?

Comment: No, the .PDF files are created in memory and sent back to the calling app as a byte[] in a response object

Comment: Set your log levels to debug and also check your container's logs.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not a spring issue. Glassfish uses a hot deploy system. Every time a file is changed or added to the file system, it will redeploy all of the resources. I would suggest creating the files outside of the server deploy directory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you suggesting that my app is touching the GlassFish filesystem, and GlassFish is redeploying everything? I do use GlassFish's /autodeploy folder (my app builds to a .WAR). But the PDFs are created in memory, not on the filesystem.

Comment: @user3385388 - yes, that is what I was suggesting. Can you add the code you're using to create the PDFs to the question above?

Comment: There is a service for creating PDFs, but Spring isn't being refreshed when calling that service. Spring is being refreshed after calling a different service, one that simply processes an XML file and saves some data to the DB. No filesystem access, all in-memory. Two interfaces are used (service and DAO) whose implementation classes are injected by Spring.

Comment: What xml files are being processed and what is being done to them? Spring does not refresh - spring has refresh capabilities. The application server does refreshes via a listener on the file system. I can't tell where in your application the file system is being modified.. but this is where your symptoms are coming from.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the XML is passed into the web service as a String. I don't think there is any filesystem access anywhere in the application, but I will double check.

Comment: Other than that - you can try @Soltirios Delimanolis' suggestion and put your log levels to DEBUG.